# Syntax clarification for PHP SimpleXML usage

Tags: php, syntax

Im referencing the PHP manual but Im getting a syntax error due to the early closing php tag-Obviously Im a newb to php but Im only attempting to assign the xml as a php string. Whats the problem here?

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<<XML //Need a clarification on '<<<XML' if possible 
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?> //This is closing my php script and causing error
<details>
<detail>
    <user>mcgraw</user>
    <dateA>09/11/1973</dateA>
    <inTime>9:00am</inTime>
    <outTime>6:00pm</outTime>
    <hours>9</hours>
    <notes>Monday</notes>
</detail>
<detail>
    <user>simpson</user>
    <dateA>08/23/1983</dateA>
    <inTime>9:00am</inTime>
    <outTime>5:30pm</outTime>
    <hours>8.5</hours>
    <notes>Thursday</notes>
</detail>
</details>
XML;
?>
```

Comment: can you give us the exact error message?

Comment: the only thing signaling the error is syntax highlighting- dreamweaver open and closing php tags are red- the xml heading closing tag is being read as the closing php tag and it is written in red.  Is this only a dreamweaver issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called PHP's Heredoc syntax. It's there to help you mark up strings without worrying about quotes.

A simpler example would be:

```
$string = <<<STR_END_DELIMITER
This is some string, I can use ' and " freely, and it wouldn't break the string.
I can also use $variables inside, and they'll evaluate.
When I'm done with the string, I'll need to type STR_END_DELIMITER; on a fresh line, without anything else (not even spaces!)
STR_END_DELIMITER;
do_stuff_with_string($string);
```

See the **[PHP Manual Entry on Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)** for more information.

Comment: according to the doc my syntax is okay, but im getting an error with CS6 Dreamweaver because the <?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?> <----is used as the closing tag to the php script and the code following is not being seen.

Comment: @mcG73 If the error is a highlighted syntax error in Dreamweaver, rather than an error from php, then it is highly likely that Dreamweaver does not understand the string syntax.

Comment: @mcG73: My PHPStorm doesn't throw any such errors, nor does PHP when I run the page.

Comment: @mcG73 perhaps you could try another editor? PHPStorm IMO is as good as it gets, but there are some reasonable free options:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166/any-good-php-ide-preferably-free-or-cheap

Comment: its a dreamweaver specific issue, I just submitted a bug report.  Thanks for your help